# Why am I getting line type in legend for ybar interval chart?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

[image]Hi,

I have a combined ybar interval and line graph as shown in attached figure, but in the legend entry the icon for bars is also shown as lines. The first 2 entries in legend PSM and MICP should display as bars as in the plot they are red and blue bars.

Here is my code: (Couldn't attach the referenced excel file whose data is being used here)

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\hoffset = 0.08in
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}
\usepackage{helvet}
%\usepackage[default,osfigures,scale=0.95]{opensans}
\usepackage{opensans}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
%\tikzexternalize
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{semilogxaxis}[
xlabel= Pore throat radius {[$\mu$m]},
   ylabel= Normalized frequency,
    ymin=0, ymax=1,
   xmin=0.001,xmax=200,
     xtick align=inside,
    ytick align=inside,
     legend style={at={(0.01,0.98)},font=\footnotesize,anchor=north west, draw=none, fill=none},
     ]
 \addplot[ybar interval, mark=none, red, fill opacity=0.1, fill=red]  table [x=PSMX,y=PSMY,col sep=comma]{Figure8.csv};
  \label{plot_one}
\addplot[ybar interval, mark=none, blue, fill opacity=0.3, fill=blue]  table [x=MICPX,y=MICPY,col sep=comma]{Figure8.csv};
  \label{plot_two}
\addplot [mark=none, black, thick, dashed]
    table [x=Dashx,y=Dashy,col sep=comma]{Figure8.csv};
    \label{plot_three}
\addplot [smooth,mark=none, blue, thick]
    table [x=PC1X,y=PC1Y,col sep=comma]{Figure8.csv};
    \label{plot_four} 
\addplot [smooth,mark=none, green, thick]
    table [x=PC2X,y=PC2Y,col sep=comma]{Figure8.csv};
    \label{plot_five} 
\addplot [smooth,mark=none, yellow, thick]
    table [x=PC3X,y=PC3Y,col sep=comma]{Figure8.csv};
    \label{plot_six} 
\addplot [smooth,mark=none, cyan, thick]
    table [x=PC4X,y=PC4Y,col sep=comma]{Figure8.csv};
    \label{plot_seven} 
\addplot [smooth,mark=none, magenta, thick]
    table [x=PC5X,y=PC5Y,col sep=comma]{Figure8.csv};
    \label{plot_eight} 
\addplot [smooth,mark=none, orange, thick]
    table [x=PC6X,y=PC6Y,col sep=comma]{Figure8.csv};
    \label{plot_nine}
\addlegendimage{/pgfplots/refstyle=plot_one}\addlegendentry{$PSM$}
\addlegendimage{/pgfplots/refstyle=plot_two}\addlegendentry{$MICP$}
\addlegendimage{/pgfplots/refstyle=plot_three}\addlegendentry{$min$ $r_{throat}$}
\addlegendimage{/pgfplots/refstyle=plot_four}\addlegendentry{$296.1$ $kPa$}
\addlegendimage{/pgfplots/refstyle=plot_five}\addlegendentry{$161.3$ $kPa$}
\addlegendimage{/pgfplots/refstyle=plot_six}\addlegendentry{$82.7$ $kPa$}
\addlegendimage{/pgfplots/refstyle=plot_seven}\addlegendentry{$6.9$ $kPa$}
\addlegendimage{/pgfplots/refstyle=plot_eight}\addlegendentry{$6.6$ $kPa$}
\addlegendimage{/pgfplots/refstyle=plot_nine}\addlegendentry{$1$ $kPa$}
\end{semilogxaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Unrelated: probably a good idea to use $\min r_{\mathrm{throat}}$, and you should use `siunitx` to typeset those quantities with unit (as there are special rules as to their spacing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `ybar interval legend` to the `\addplot`s with the bar plots to set the correct legend type. This is described in the `pgfplots` manual. When doing `\addplot [ybar interval]` that only changes how the datapoints are visualized. Legends, ticks etc. are only modified when adding `ybar interval` in the options for the `axis` environment. However, that doesn't make sense when you want to mix different plot types, and as such you have to specify which legend type to use if you want something else than the standard `line legend`.

A shortened example with some random values is found below.

Note also that `\addlegendentry` doesn't apply to the `\addplot` or `\addlegendimage` immediately preceding it, only the order matters. I.e., the first `\addplot`/`\addlegendimage` corresponds to the first `\addlegendentry` etc. Therefore, all your `\addlegendimage`s are irrelevant in this case.

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{semilogxaxis}[
domain=1:10,
xlabel= Pore throat radius {[$\mu$m]},
   ylabel= Normalized frequency,
    ymin=0, ymax=1,
   xmin=0.001,xmax=200,
     xtick align=inside,
    ytick align=inside,
     legend style={at={(0.01,0.98)},font=\footnotesize,anchor=north west, draw=none, fill=none},
     ]
     
 \addplot[
    ybar interval, mark=none, red, fill opacity=0.1, fill=red,
        ybar interval legend  % <-- added this
       ] {rnd};
  \label{plot_one}
\addplot [mark=none, black, thick, dashed] {rnd};
    \label{plot_three}

\addlegendentry{$PSM$}
\addlegendentry{$\min r_{\mathrm{throat}}$}
\end{semilogxaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Also unrelated, but might be best to use the `geometry` package for all page layout stuff, so instead of `\hoffset=X` and so on, have `\usepackage{geometry}  \geometry{margin=1in, hoffset=0.08in}`.

Comment: Thank you very much.